# Should I use a Bayesian multilevel model to detect outliers?

Tags: multilevel-analysis, outliers, hierarchical-bayesian

I have approximately-log-normal price data. The data is hierarchically structured. Let's say there are three levels, so the notation for a log-transformed observation could be $x_{ijk}$, with the indexing decreasing in granularity to the right. A minority of the price data is obviously too high or too low to be valid. What is not obvious are the cut-off points for the definition of a credible price. My current method is stepwise:

Step 1: Define outliers as observations that lie below $\frac{1}{3}x_{jk}$ and above $3x_{jk}$, where $x_{jk}$ is the mean across observations the observations in grouping $jk$.

Step2: For groups $jk$ with fewer than 10 observations, define outliers instead as lying outside the bounds of $\frac{1}{3}x_k$ and $3x_k$, where $x_k$ is the mean across $x_{jk}$ within group $k$.

Step 3: For groups $k$ with fewer than 10 observations, define outliers instead as lying outside the bounds of $\frac{1}{3}x$ and $3x$, where $x$ is the mean across $x_k$.

This sounds to me like an informal attempt at defining outliers based on a multilevel model. I wonder if I could fit a multilevel model with an informative population-level hyper-prior distribution, and then define outliers as observations that lie outside 95% or 99% credible intervals of $\mu_{ijk}$, where $\mu_{ijk}$ is the mean parameter of the conditional log-normal distribution for group $ijk$.

Are there credible examples of this in the literature? Do you have experience with this outlier-detection method and have some perspective? Are there theoretical justifications for this method? WWAGD? (What Would Andrew Gelman Do?)

Comment: "some sort of price-reduction incentive contaminated the data"  In most cases, variation in price such as this is the signal, not the contaminant. It's not unusual to have most of the sales volume occur during these "contaminated" time periods.

Comment: I'm not going to call this an "answer," but I think using the multilevel model for outlier detection sounds like a good idea. I don't even think you need anything as fancy as credible intervals. If you're using lme4, for instance, you get some shrinkage of the group level parameters, but they lead to individual predictions. I'd start by plotting observed vs fitted and looking for wild points.

Comment: "In most cases, variation in price such as this is the signal, not the contaminant." I understand what you're saying, but for reasons beyond the scope of this discussion, that's not the case here.

Comment: Another possible model is a mixture distribution for log price with a central normal distribution + some long-tailed extra component. You can then for each point get a posterior probability that it belongs to one or the other mixture component. I am not quite sure on how to set up a good hierarchical model for this (given that that would seem appropriate for your setting).